# Trouble launching Repton 1 and 2 on Windows 10

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, repton-1, repton-2

I have recently installed a copy of Repton 1 that I brought from Superior Interactive about 5 years ago on my Windows 10 laptop. Upon launching the game, the screen flashes between black and white and is unresponsive. After over 5 minutes, it stays in the same state. It worked properly in Windows 7, Vista and XP, yet crashes in their respective compatibility modes in Windows 10. I have tried every single option in compatibility settings yet it still crashes.

If it helps, I am running Windows 10 Pro 32-bit, with an intel i3 CPU M350 and 4GB of memory. The same problem occurs with Repton 2, while not with Repton 3.

Comment: Well the Superior Interactive website claims that all three Repton games can be used on Windows 10, so unless the developer is lying, incompatibility with the OS is not the problem here.

Comment: Do these games have DRM's? E.g. securom or the like?

Comment: No, they need a product key, that I correctly entered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from Superior Interactive, the [publisher of the Repton games](http://www.superiorinteractive.com/repton/). We have updated versions of Repton 1 and Repton 2, which are definitely compatible with Windows 10.

You can [contact us](http://www.superiorinteractive.com/contact/) to obtain these updated versions of the Repton 1 and Repton 2 software.

Comment: Hi, @SuperiorInteractive, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately your earlier one probably looked a bit like spam which is why it was removed. I think it is definitely helpful that customers can contact you for support. I have merged information from your previous answer here, and linked explicitly to your contact us page, rather than to the direct email - that way if your information is updated on your website, it will still be accessible from here.